# WLAN passive scanning in wpa_supplicant Android

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, network-scan, wpa-supplicant

I have been trying to trigger WLAN passive scanning in android wpa_supplicant, the patch for which is provided in http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2683858

But the android device still performs active scans for WLANs.

Going through the nl80211 source file "external/wpa_supplicant/src/drivers/driver_nl80211.c", I found that if parameter "num_ssids" in struct "wpa_driver_scan_params" has value 0, then the device will perform passive scan. But even zero value does not initiate passive scan.

Does this mean that passive scanning is disabled in firmware??

The device used is nexus 5 working on cyanogenmod and wifi chipset is bcm4339.